# crawl a website for its href value from anchor tags using java

Tags: java, recursion, web-crawler

Baseurl = "test.com/url"
I am trying to crawl the href from anchor links  from a website that has test.com/url base page and i recursivly need to go to all the hrefs and and get all the achor tags values and store them in an array. I have already implemented it below, but it turns out it is a infinite loop and i can't figure why the infinite loop is happening. 
the values for the href are stored such as "./jobs";

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*; 

public class test{
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
       value("http://www.test.com/urls");
    }

    public static int getIndexOf(String str, String c, int n) {
    int pos = str.indexOf(c, 0);
    while (n-- > 0 && pos != -1){
      pos = str.indexOf(c, pos + 1);
    }
    return pos;
  }

  public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  public static void value(String urladdr){

        try {
            URL my_url = new URL(urladdr);
              System.out.println(urladdr);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(my_url.openStream()));
                           String strTemp = "";

                while(true){
                    try{
                        strTemp = br.readLine();
                    }catch(NullPointerException e){
                        br.close();
                        break;
                    }

                        if(strTemp.contains("<a href=\"/urls/")){

                                 if(!list.contains(compute(strTemp))){
                                        list.add(compute(strTemp));
                                        System.out.println(list);
                                        }else{
                                            br.close();
                                break;
                                        }
                      }
                 } 
                        br.close();
             for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            value("http://www.test.com"+list.get(i));
                        }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
  }

  public static String compute(String strTemp){
         int n = getIndexOf(strTemp, "/urls", 0);
              String[] a = strTemp.substring(n).split(">");
                String url = a[0].replaceAll("\"", "");
                String value = a[1].replaceAll("</a", "");
                return url;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why would you expect a `NullPointerException` to be thrown when you try to read past the end of your input?

Comment: I did realize that the exception is pointless but still I have a infinite loop, still doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the java docs for `BufferedReader` / `readLine` you will see it says

```
A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination 
characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached
```

so simply by changing your code to test for this will help you on you way.

```
    strTemp = br.readLine();
    if (strTemp == null) {
        break;
    }


     ....
    finally {
        br.close();
    }
```

Comment: but here i am not doing anything with a string. I am just recuring going into another get request to find out the url

Comment: maybe you forgot what the question you asked was.

Comment: Also in the above code, you are adding to a list and then every time to are processing the whole loop again.